# Java - Read a specific part from a line ( between " " )

Tags: java

In Java ,i have this line from a log file :

```
    Hello "My name is Vader"
```

i need to take as a string all the words between " "

i only managed to read them as words(strings) separately, with the

```
    matcher.nextToken()
```

but i need to take the whole string between " "

Thank you in advance!

Comment: regex can help you...

Comment: Often before asking such questions it's better to first do a Google search for similar questions like this one:[Google Search: site:stackoverflow.com java extract string between quotes](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+extract+string+between+quotes), and then reading the best hits. There's nothing new under the sun, and this same type of question has been repeatedly asked previously.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String extractTextBetweenQuotes(String str) {
    int start = str.indexOf('"');
    if (start < 0) throw new IllegalStateException("no first quote");
    int end = str.indexOf('"', start + 1);
    if (end < 0) throw new IllegalStateException("no second quote");
    return str.substring(start + 1, end);
}
```

This assumes that you always have 2 double quotes in your input. If not, it's 'throw exception' policy has to be changed to something different.